# The Largest integer value of $k$ for which the equation $e^x - 1 - k \tan^{-1}(x) = 0$ posses only one real root.

Tags: calculus

> The Largest integer value of $k$ for which the equation $e^x - 1 - k \tan^{-1}(x) = 0$ posses only one real root.

I think we have to make graph but I was not able to analyse it so as to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{x}-1-k\tan^{-1}(x).$ Note that $f(0)=0$ for all values of $k$. So we need to check if there is any other solution to $f(x)=0$.
$$f'(x)=e^x-\frac{k}{x^2+1}$$

- $k\leq 0 \implies f'(x)>0\implies $ $f(x)$ has only one real root.
- $k=1\implies$ $f'(x) \begin{cases}
  <0 & x<0\\
  0 & x = 0\\
  >0&x>0
  \end{cases}\implies $ $f(x)$ has only one real root.
- $k>1\implies \exists x\neq 0 : f'(x) = 0\implies$ f(x) has a real root other than $x=0.$

Therefore, the answer is $k=1$.

I leave it you to think about how the graph of $f(x)$ looks like in each to the above cases and find the reason why the arguments are true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x=0$ is always a root of $f(x)=e^x - 1 - k \tan^{-1} x$. Also note that $f(\infty)\to \infty$. Therefore, in order for $f(x)$ to have only one root at $x=0$, the following must holds,

$$f(-\infty) =- 1+\frac{k\pi}{2} < 0$$

which yields $k < \frac2\pi < 1$. Thus, $k=0$ is the largest integer. Indeed, for $k=0$, $f(x) = e^x-1$ monotonically increases, having only one root at $x=0$.